# Bivariate Correlation issue - one variable is normally distributed, the other is not. Also, is likert score suitable?

Tags: correlation, likert

I’m looking at whether specific morning use of phones (measured on a 4 point likert scale with a single question about morning phone use, 1=Less than hour.....to 4=“I don’t use my phone in the morning”) is related to poor sleep (measured using a totalled sleep score from a validated sleep measure,PSQI)

My questions are:

The likert scale provides each participant with a score of 1-4.
The sleep score provides each participant with a larger scale score.

1. Would these variables be suited to a normal Pearson’s R test? Or would spearman’s rank be better since the “morning use” variable is a ranked item? (Ordinal data type seems more appropriate rather than ratio).
2. One of the variables, sleep score is not normally distributed. (Skewness z-score is 2.9), must I abandon the Pearson test? Or....
3. Should I transform the data that isn’t normally distributed?

I’m quite new to stats so trying my best to work this out. Hopefully some advice will get me on track.

Comment: You're implying that morning use is not normally distributed, but four spikes a normal distribution does not make. Both variables are ordinal, on this evidence.